# How assign names for every key

Tags: php

i have array

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];


$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];


$email = $_POST['email'];


$address = $_POST['address'];


$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];


$comment = $_POST['comment'];


$data = array (     "Full Name :" => $fullname,
                "Company :" => $company_name,
                "email :" => $email,
                "address :" => $address,
                "telephone :" => $telephone,
                "mobile :" => $mobile,
                "comment :" => $comment);
```

i want show resul such as  `(Fullname : $fullname  Email: $email)` to send it as email

and add array in string using `implode(" ",$data)`

what can i do??

Answer (score 2):

```
$fields = array('fullname' => 'Full Name', 'company_name' => 'Company', 'email'=>'Email', 'address' => 'Address', 'telephone'=>'Telephone', 'comment'=>'Comment');

$string = "(";
foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_label)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$field_name]))
    {
        $string .= $field_label .' :' . $_POST[$field_name] . ' ';
    }
}
$string .= ')';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a map of your $_POST keys mapping to their respective labels:

```
$arr = array('fullname' => 'Fullname:'); // etc

$data = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(array_key_exists($k, $arr)) {
        $data[$arr[$k]] = $v;
    }
}
```

I would just use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to print it out for the email:

> `var_export()` gets structured
>   information about the given variable.
>   It is similar to `var_dump()` with one
>   exception: the returned representation
>   is valid PHP code.

So:

```
$output = var_export($data, true);
// $output goes into your email
```